# How do I use Steam In-Home Streaming between Fedora (client) and Windows 8 (server)?

Tags: steam, steam-in-home-streaming, fedora

My main gaming machine is a Windows 8 box attached to my TV. When my husband wants to watch TV, I like to play games from my laptop. Since switching OS from Ubuntu to Fedora on my laptop, Steam has stopped detecting the gaming machine as an in-home streaming server.

What is preventing this, and how can I remedy it so that I can once again stream games to my laptop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the solution -- Fedora's firewall is blocking Steam by default. (Good firewall! Sit. Stay. Steam is a friend. Say hello).

Fire up `/usr/bin/firewall-config` (or just enter "firewall" in your DE's application menu serach box) to add an exception. Once it's open:

1. From the drop-down at the top, select the **Permanent** configuration.
2. From the tabs below that, select the **Services** tab.
3. From the *Service* pane at the left, click the **Add Service** button
4. In the dialog that appears, name the service `steam-stream`. Any version number should suffice (I used `0.1`). Ensure the new service is selected when the dialog is closed.
5. Ensure the *Ports and Protocols* tab is selected, then click **Add** at the bottom of the pane.
6. Enter `27036` as the port number and `tcp` as the protocol, then click **OK**
7. Repeat steps 5 and 6 to add exceptions for:

   - `udp` port `27036`
   - `tcp` port `27031`
   - `udp` port `27031`
8. From the *tabs below the Configuration dropdown*, select **Zones**
9. From the pane on the left, ensure the `public` zone is selected
10. From the pane on the right, ensure the **Services** tab is selected
11. In the list of services, scroll until you find the `steam-stream` service, and check the associated checkbox
12. (Not sure if this is necessary) From the menu bar, select **Options > Reload Firewalld**
13. Restart Steam